# Blacklist [whats-your-favourite] tag?

Tags: support, tag-block-request

[whats-your-favourite](/questions/tagged/whats-your-favourite) only has eight questions, but all save one of them fall squarely in the GTKY/poll/shopping list bin as far as I can see.

There's [a brand new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651781/what-are-your-favorite-objective-c-categories) on that list (which made me aware of this tag), and it seems to me that this tag is likely to only be used for similar poll-type questions.

Blacklist that sucker?

Comment: I like the idea of those questions (as you can tell from my response to that new one in SO), but I think they need a different home.  A separate section of SO, or a discussion based programming site.

Comment: While we're at it, let's close that sucker too!

Comment: At least http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520283/say-you-had-to-pick-one-programming-language-to-use-the-rest-of-your-life-po and maybe some others need delete votes.

Comment: @chown: there's certainly useful information to be gained from _some_ discussions in this vein. http://cocoadev.com might be a good place for "What's your favorite Obj-C category?"

Answer (score 1):

I'd close/delete all open and poll-like questions and synonymize/merge the tag with [polls](/questions/tagged/polls).

Comment: @agf: it's already been suggested and I personally disagree a bit. "poll" has also a meaning in web development (ajax) and database world. Or, at least split and rename it to "ajax-poll" or "db-poll".

Comment: You're right! It's a bad suggestion. But there are a lot of questions in there that use it in the same way as `polls`. Probably better just to retag them.